# Can we add a suggestion to "Ask Question" to include your locality?

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

So many questions get comments "What country are you in?" "Where are you doing this?" etc. etc.

Can we add a more obvious "Add your country!" to the "Ask Question" page?

Comment: This has come up before and I think SE people said they couldn't.  I wonder if they can now?

Comment: Not all questions require location. That said, I think new users should be prompted to add location on their profile. That would help a bit.

Answer (score 4):

This is now *somewhat* possible. It wouldn't show for every single question, but we do have the ability to provide more just-in-time help based on the *tags* that people use when posting.

Can you give me some tags where it would be pretty important for them to specify a location within the question? I might be able to make quick work of this if so :)

Comment: Thanks!   My suggestion for tags is anything that matches "\*tax\*" (26 tags currently), legal, foreign-exchange, travel, "\*insurance" (8 tags currently).

Comment: Anyone else have any suggestions for other tags that frequently need locality and would benefit from a prompt?

Comment: Retirement is one that needs a country; Social Security, 401K and IRA are US only.

Comment: I'd add "student-loan", "education-savings", "mortgage", "pmi", "healthcare", "hsa", "health-spending-account", "flexible-spending-account", "bankruptcy", "foreclosure", "vat", "gst", "withholding", "consumer-protection", "government", "regulation", "estate-planning", "will", and "trust" to the list.

Comment: I think a list of tags where the location wouldn't matter would be much shorter...

Comment: Kinda seeing this as a separate feature now, since there are just so many. Matching tax* isn't hard, but there are so many one-off tags to match. What we _might_ be able to do, and I have to look into it, is have a per-site configurable paragraph under the tag input field on the questions/ask page. This is the place to say "If your question goes beyond general fiscal advice that could equally apply to anyone regardless of location, you should consider indicating your location in your question if you'd like to receive a timely answer" or something to that effect. Lemme think on it a spell.

Comment: A per-site configurable paragraph isn't a bad idea, but on the original idea, how about a simple *moderator-configurable* list of tags, so the burden of maintaining such a list isn't on Stack Exchange staff?