# How to indicate that credit score related questions need a location tag?

Tags: discussion, country-tags

There have been several discussions over the years about requiring all posts to have a location tag, requiring all new users to specify their location in their profile, providing a prompt for a location tag on posts that have certain other tags that are known to be location-dependent (tax, pensions, etc) or similar.

Some examples:

- [Should *all* questions that *depend-on* a country include a country tag?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/should-all-questions-that-depend-on-a-country-include-a-country-tag)
- [Suggestion: Require new users to include their country in user profile](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/606/suggestion-require-new-users-to-include-their-country-in-user-profile)
- [Can we add a suggestion to "Ask Question" to include your locality?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/can-we-add-a-suggestion-to-ask-question-to-include-your-locality/)
- [Could a regional tag (or a new "international" tag) be made mandatory?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/could-a-regional-tag-or-a-new-international-tag-be-made-mandatory/)

I feel as though recently there have been lots of posts tagged "credit score" that are not also tagged with a location. I have commented on many of them asking the user to indicate where they are, but oftentimes they get answered with a US-based answer (which, to be fair, based on purely statistical probability is probably what the asker wanted) and then the OP never comes back to indicate where they actually are - leaving the question, and answer, untagged as to location and potentially confusing other non-US readers in the future.

Have we given up attempting to find a solution to these tagging issues? It may be my confirmation bias but I don't seem to notice the same issues occurring anything like as much these days with tax or other location-specific questions, despite the lack of any actual concrete solution having been implemented.

Would it be worth editing the tag-tooltips for these tags to prominently note "SPECIFY YOUR LOCATION" or similar?

Comment: Related: [Guidelines for asking for/editing country tags in questions from new users](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2110/10997)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to ban all non-US users from posting on SE and be done with it. Even if questions are tagged with non-US locations, answerers apparently either don't read the tags, or maybe can't even imagine that the rest of the world might be different from the USA,

Comment: At a glance there only appear to be about 15 countries that use a credit score https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_score . This may help identify which credit scoring system is in play from jargon or branding, for example a user asking about Sesame and credit would very likely be in China, or CIBIL would indicate India. So *a* solution might be country specific tags for the local jargon that describes the credit score system name or overseeing organization name.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for editing the tag wikis and hoping for the best. Personally I haven't noticed the problem being particularly biased towards credit scoring questions.